# AVAudioRecorder in iOS 9 Not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, avaudiosession

I'm using `AVAudioRecorder` to record a audio file. The code I'm using works perfectly fine in iOS 8 and below but since the latest update of iOS 9 the recording seems to have stopped working.

I tried logging the properties of `AVAudioRecorder` object and even after calling the "record" function in `AVAudioRecorder` the `isRecording` is showing as NO and when the "stop" function is called i get the call back in the delegate
 `- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag;` with success flag as NO

```c
audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %ld %@", [err domain], (long)[err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];

recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:8] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.m4a", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,@"sample"];

NSLog(@"RecorderFilePath : %@",recorderFilePath);

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
err = nil;
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];

//prepare to record
[recorder setDelegate:self];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputAvailable;

[recorder record];
```

Please advise if i'm doing something wrong in the code.

Comment: A very simple reason may be: Is access to the microphone allowed in the settings for the app?

Comment: No,i have double checked this the permission for accessing mic is ON.

Comment: Does the problem happen on a device, and if yes, which one? (iPad 1/2/3/4 / Air...?)

Comment: i have checked in iPad mini,iPhone 5,5s,6.

Comment: In one of my projects I am working with, audio recording is used and for MPEGAAC these settings are used: File extension is "mp4" / recorderSettings = @{ AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityMin), AVEncoderBitRateKey: @(8), AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @(1), AVSampleRateKey: @(11025.0) }; -- sorry for the cramped copy&paste. Maybe some of your settings are not working with iOS9 any more. (I likely have to fix some audio encoding issues myself soon, so I'm keen to know what your "problem" is :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,nil];


// [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
if (recorderHelium)
{
    recorderHelium = nil;
}

recorderHelium = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:recordedAudioFilePath] settings:recordSetting error:nil];
recorderHelium.delegate = self;
recorderHelium.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorderHelium prepareToRecord];
[recorderHelium record];
```

And also import and include these files:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```